# toLowerCase wrong lower characters " İ "

Tags: javascript, utf-8, lowercase

I actually have a simple problem. you will understand what I mean when you examine the following code.

```
function isPalindrome(string){
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  var charArr = string.split('');

  charArr.forEach( char => {
    console.log(char);
  })
  console.log(charArr.length)
}

isPalindrome("İris");
```

output

```
i
 ̇  <- what is this ?
r
i
s
5
```

adding extra characters as you see. I could not solve this problem. Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: Have you tried [`toLocaleLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca wow its working. What's the difference with toLowerCase?

Comment: "İ" is composed of two Unicode characters, the I character and the dot on top of it. `.toLocaleLowerCase()` recognizes it as a single letter.

Comment: @JJJ I think that `.toLowerCase()` is what turns it into a Latin lower-case "i" plus the Unicode "combining dot above" character (decimal 775).

Comment: it's not working on chrome console. I think that shouldn't be working because that character is not English. how that can be the same with lowercase of English character.

Comment: @chase Choi, Works with Chrome

Comment: It's not working with my latest chrome on windows7. guess it's related with locale on device?

Comment: I am using windows 7 and my chrome browser is up to date , its working.

Comment: This relates to UTF-16, not UTF-8. String is UTF-16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is working.
You've to remove the possible special chars after using `toLowerCase`. You could use `replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')`

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/7psvx28r/)

```
function isPalindrome(str){
  var charArr = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').split(""); //toLowerCase --> remove special characters --> split the string

  charArr.forEach( char => {
    console.log(char);
  })
  console.log(charArr.length)
}

isPalindrome("İris");
```

Comment: The easier way to do this is with theLocaleLowerCase ()

Comment: it's more reliable answer.

Comment: `toLocaleLowerCase` works not in every browser. In my chrome 62.0.3202 (german language) it doesn't work.

Comment: `"string".toLocaleLowerCase()..replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')` is most secure solution.